# gtk+ checkbutton settings

Tags: python, c, gtk

Is there a way to use `set_active` on a gtkCheckButton but without the user being able to press/toggle the said button?

In other words, I want to programmatically control the `active state` of the CheckButton but I don't want the user to be able to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[active](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtktogglebutton.html#properties-gtktogglebutton)" property of the gtk.[ToggleButton](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtktogglebutton.html) combined with the "[sensitive](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#properties-gtkwidget)" property of the gtk.[Widget](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html) should do what you want. You should just be able to do

```
checkbox1.set_sensitive(False)
checkbox1.set_active(True)
```

...to check it and have it remain unchangeable.